# Trouble with creating list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, finance

I made a stock screener that gives the technicals of stocks that meat my criteria, at the end, I want it to print a concise list of stocks that do meet my criteria. I tried to use the append function, but it only prints one stock, instead, I want it to print the ticker of each stock that prints, for example 'mmm',...

The current output looks like this.
MMM
Trailing P/E: 17.61
Return on Equity: 54.34%
Revenue: 32.35B
Quarterly Revenue Growth: -5.00%

---

```
def scrape(stock_list, interested, technicals):
    for each_stock in stock_list:
        technicals = scrape_yahoo(each_stock)
        condition_1 = float(technicals.get('Return on Equity',0).replace('%','').replace('N/A','-100')) > 25
        condition_2 = float(technicals.get('Trailing P/E',0).replace('N/A','')) > 15
        condition_3 = float(technicals.get('Price/Book (mrq)',0)) <15
        if (condition_1 and condition_2)==True:
            print(each_stock)
            SuggestedStocks = []
            SuggestedStocks.append(each_stock)  
            for ind in interested: 

                print(ind + ": "+ technicals[ind])         
            print("------")
            time.sleep(1)                                                    # Use delay to avoid getting flagged as bot
    #return technicals
    print(SuggestedStocks)


def main():

    stock_list = ['MMM', 'ABT', 'ABBV', 'ABMD', 'ACN', 'ATVI', 'ADBE', 'AMD']
    interested = ['Trailing P/E', 'Return on Equity', 'Revenue', 'Quarterly Revenue Growth']
    technicals = {}

    tech = scrape(stock_list, interested, technicals)
    print(tech)
main()
```

It only prints the ticker of the last stock that meets my criteria:ADBE.

Comment: Why are you initializing `SuggestedStocks` to an empty list inside the loop before the `append()`?

Comment: I did not downvote - please stop making untrue assumptions and keep the discussion on the code. For example `if (condition_1 and condition_2)==True:`, could be more pythonistic as `if condition_1 and condition_2:` - Happy Coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you reset suggested stocks in each loop `SuggestedStocks = []` you should initialize it outside of the loop.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look out for that one in the future!